# ¿Es posible pasar una petición hecha con form a realizarse con fetch o axios y como hacerlo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Estoy actualizando un código realizado para enviar datos mediante `POST`, que utiliza un `form` para realizar dicha acción.

ejemplo de como se utiliza con `form`:

```
<form name='form' method='post' action='https://url.test'>
    <input name='s_' type='hidden' value={s_} />
    <input name='c_' type='hidden' value={r} />
    <input name='t_' type='hidden' value={t_} />
    <input name='t_i' type='hidden' value={t_i} />
    <input name='val_1' type='hidden' value={val_1} />
    <input name='val_2' type='hidden' value={val_2} />
    <input name='val_3' type='hidden' value={val_3} />
    <input name='val_4' type='hidden' value={val_4} />
    <input name='val_5' type='hidden' value={val_5} />
    <input name='val_6' type='hidden' value={val_6} />
    <button>
        <ImgContainer>
            <img src={img1} alt='imageTest' />
        </ImgContainer>
    </button>
</form>
```

intente realizar lo siguiente

```
const resp = await fetch(
    `https://url.test`,
    {
      'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      method: 'POST',
      'Content-Type': 'application / x-www-form-urlencoded',
      body: data
    },
);
```

la petición anterior me regresa el siguiente error.

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://url.test (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

Comment: no es un error, es una restriccion del backend, desabilita `CORS` en el backend

Comment: @manrriquemenesesyaranga no hay que deshabilitar cors. Hay que permitir solo el acceso correspondiente. Sacar algo nunca es una buena idea.